# list comprehension using if

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a one-line list comprehension that takes a list of tuples and adds them to a new list if the second element of the tuple is not equal to 0

```
my_list = [x in my_list if x[1] != 0]
```

this is the code I wrote, says I have invalid syntax

Comment: `[x for x in my_list if x[1] != 0]`

Comment: hey @Delgan, post that as an answer so you can get the points!

Comment: @welch No, I think this question should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @welch good suggestion, but actually as Delgan says if things are caused by typos or obvious little mistakes, they're generally closed - sometimes with a little comment to tell the person what went wrong. It's just something you pick up on after you've been here a while - hope this helped explain :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x[1] != 0]
```